# Vim plugin MarkDown Headings

Tags: plugin, markdown, vimscript, vim

This is my first Vim plugin and is intended to assist with adding, and editing, MarkDown headings. Features include changing the heading depth, auto-update heading reference links, and adding link title (on hover) text. Currently everything *seems* to function as designed, however, as this the first Vim script project that I've published, I'm certain that there is room for improvement.

---

### Questions

- Are there any features for modification/customization that need to be added?

> Or in other-words, should I offer leader/command key customization, and if so what are the best practices for achieving that?

- Is there a way to throw error codes, and if so what are the correct error codes to throw within this plugin?

> Examples would be super helpful for both myself and future readers.

- Have I made any mistakes?

---

### Requirements

This plugin is tested on Linux based operating systems, but suggestions on how to make it OS agnostic are certainly welcomed; regardless Vim should be installed prior to using this plugin, eg...

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

---

### Setup

[Source code](https://github.com/vim-utilities/markdown-headings) is maintained on GitHub, as are the documentation files and [`README.md`](https://github.com/vim-utilities/markdown-headings/blob/main/.github/README.md). Included within this question are the TLDR and source `.vim` script code files.

```
mkdir -vp ~/git/hub/vim-utilities

cd ~/git/hub/vim-utilities

git clone git@github.com:vim-utilities/markdown-headings.git
```

If **not** utilizing some form of Vim plugin manager, then the [`linked-install.sh`](https://github.com/vim-utilities/markdown-headings/blob/main/linked-install.sh) script may be run on most 'nix devices...

```
./linked-install.sh
```

... which will symbolically link plugin scripts and documentation, and update Vim doc. tags.

---

### Usage

Features of this plugin automatically activate if detected `filetype` is `markdown`

**Example Usage**

0. Write a line of text...

```
Heading line to be
```

1. Use Vim leader sequence to convert line into level `2` MarkDown heading...

```
<Leader>h2
```

2. Example results...

```
## Heading line to be
```

3. Use Vim command to build Heading Link with title text...

```
:Hl Text about heading
```

4. Example results...

```
## Heading line to be
[heading__heading_line_to_be]: #heading-line-to-be "Text about heading"
```

5. Edit text of heading...

```
## Edited heading line
[heading__heading_line_to_be]: #heading-line-to-be "Text about heading"
```

6. Use Vim leader sequence to update Heading Link...

```
<Leader>hl
```

7. Example results...

```
## Edited heading line
[heading__edited_heading_line]: #edited-heading-line "Text about heading"
```

... Note, either `:Hl` or `<Leader>hl` will update any references to the heading within the document too!

For example for a table of contents similar to...

```
- [Link to Some Heading][heading__heading_line_to_be]
```

... would be updated to...

```
- [Link to Some Heading][heading__edited_heading_line]
```

8. Convert the level two heading to a level three heading...

```
<Leader>h3
```

... example results...

```
### Edited heading line
```

---

### Source Code

[**`plugin/markdown-heading-link.vim`**](https://github.com/vim-utilities/markdown-headings/blob/main/plugin/markdown-heading-link.vim)

```
#!/usr/bin/env vim


autocmd FileType markdown call s:Register_Leader()
autocmd FileType markdown call s:Register_Commands()


""
" Registers Normal mode leader sequences
function! s:Register_Leader()
  nnoremap <Leader>hl :call MarkDown_Headings_Make_Link()<cr>
endfunction

""
" Registers Ex mode commands
function! s:Register_Commands()
  command! -nargs=* Hl call MarkDown_Headings_Make_Link(<f-args>)
endfunction


""
" Returns lower-cased string, replacing spaces with dashes and striping non-alpha/numeric characters
" @param {string} heading_text - Word to sluggify
" @return {string}
" @author S0AndS0
" @license AGPL-3.0
" @example
" echo s:Sluggify('## Spam Flavored Ham')
" #> spam-flavored-ham
function! s:Sluggify(heading_text)
  let l:trimmed_line = substitute(a:heading_text, '^#* ', '', '')
  let l:lowered_line = tolower(l:trimmed_line)
  let l:sanitized_line = substitute(l:lowered_line, '[^a-z0-9 ]', '', 'g')
  let l:dashed_line = substitute(l:sanitized_line, ' ', '-', 'g')
  let l:slugged_line = substitute(l:dashed_line, '--*', '-', 'g')
  return l:slugged_line
endfunction


""
" Returns heading ref/tag for linking within document
" @param {string} slugged_line - Slugged string to transmute into heading tag
" @return {string}
" @author S0AndS0
" @license AGPL-3.0
" @example
" echo s:Taggify_Slug('spam-flavored-ham')
" #> heading__spam_flavored_ham
function! s:Taggify_Slug(slugged_line)
  return 'heading__' . substitute(a:slugged_line, '-', '_', 'g')
endfunction


""
" Updates heading link references for entire document
" @param {string} old_reference - Heading reference to search document for
" @param {string} new_reference - Replacement heading reference
" @author S0AndS0
" @license AGPL-3.0
" @throws Error codes that are **not** E486
" @example
" s:Update_Refs('heading__spam_flavored_ham]', 'heading__raspberry_jam]')
function! s:Update_Refs(old_reference, new_reference)
  try
    execute ':%s/\[' . a:old_reference . '/\[' . a:new_reference . '/g'
  catch
    if v:exception !~ '^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E486'
      throw v:exception
    endif
  endtry
endfunction


""
" Adds or updates reference link for heading under cursor postilion
" @param {string[]|number[]} ... - List of words and/or numbers
" @author S0AndS0
" @license AGPL-3.0
" @throws {string} 'Did not detect MarkDown heading!'
function! MarkDown_Headings_Make_Link(...)
  let l:current_line = getline('.')
  if match(l:current_line, '#') < 0
    throw 'Did not detect MarkDown heading!'
  endif

  let l:cursor_position = getpos('.')
  let l:slugged_line = s:Sluggify(l:current_line)
  let l:tag_line = s:Taggify_Slug(slugged_line)

  let l:next_line = getline(l:cursor_position[1] + 1)
  let l:regex_link_without_title = "\[[a-z0-9_]*\]: #[a-z0-9\-]*"
  let l:regex_link_with_title = l:regex_link_without_title . " \"[[:print:]]*\""

  let l:heading_tag = '[' . l:tag_line . ']'
  let l:heading_title = join(a:000)
  let l:heading_link_text = l:heading_tag . ': #' . l:slugged_line
  if len(l:heading_title) > 0
    let l:heading_link_text .= ' "' . l:heading_title . '"'
  elseif match(l:next_line, l:regex_link_with_title) >= 0
    let l:heading_title = split(l:next_line, '"')[-1]
    if len(l:heading_title) > 0
      let l:heading_link_text .= ' "' . l:heading_title . '"'
    endif
  endif

  if match(l:next_line, l:regex_link_without_title) < 0
    execute "normal! A\n" . l:heading_link_text
  else
    let l:old_heading_tag = l:next_line[0:match(l:next_line, ']')]
    execute "normal! j0c$" . l:heading_link_text

    let l:tag_find = l:old_heading_tag[1:len(l:old_heading_tag)]
    let l:tag_replace = l:heading_tag[1:len(l:heading_tag)]
    call s:Update_Refs(l:tag_find, l:tag_replace)
  endif

  call setpos('.', cursor_position)
  if len(l:heading_title) == 0
    execute "normal! jA" . ' ""'
    :startinsert
  endif
endfunction
```

---

[**`plugin/markdown-heading-transform.vim`**](https://github.com/vim-utilities/markdown-headings/blob/main/plugin/markdown-heading-transform.vim)

```
#!/usr/bin/env vim


autocmd FileType markdown call s:Register_Leader()
autocmd FileType markdown call s:Register_Commands()


""
" Registers Normal mode leader sequences
function! s:Register_Leader()
  nnoremap <Leader>h0 :call MarkDown_Heading_Transform(0)<cr>
  nnoremap <Leader>h1 :call MarkDown_Heading_Transform(1)<cr>
  nnoremap <Leader>h2 :call MarkDown_Heading_Transform(2)<cr>
  nnoremap <Leader>h3 :call MarkDown_Heading_Transform(3)<cr>
  nnoremap <Leader>h4 :call MarkDown_Heading_Transform(4)<cr>
endfunction


""
" Registers Ex mode commands
function! s:Register_Commands()
  command! -nargs=1 H call MarkDown_Heading_Transform(<f-args>)
endfunction


""
" Transforms current line to MarkDown heading of defined depth
" @param {number} depth - Heading depth, eg. `0`, or `1`, or `-1`, etc
" @author S0AndS0
" @license AGPL-3.0
" @example text
" foo bar
" @example input
" \h3
" @example output
" ### foo bar
function! MarkDown_Heading_Transform(depth)
  let l:cursor_position = getpos('.')
  let l:current_line = getline('.')
  let l:trimmed_line = substitute(l:current_line, '^#* ', '', '')
  let l:current_depth = len(substitute(l:current_line, '[^#*].*', '', ''))

  if a:depth == l:current_depth
    return
  elseif a:depth > l:current_depth && l:current_depth == 0
    let l:cursor_x_offset = a:depth + 1 - l:current_depth
  elseif a:depth < l:current_depth && a:depth == 0
    let l:cursor_x_offset = a:depth - 1 - l:current_depth
  else
    let l:cursor_x_offset = a:depth - l:current_depth
  endif

  if a:depth > 0
    let l:headings = repeat('#', a:depth)
    let l:heading_line = join([l:headings, ' ', l:trimmed_line], '')
    let l:cursor_position[2] += l:cursor_x_offset
  elseif a:depth == 0
    let l:heading_line = l:trimmed_line
    if l:cursor_position[2] > 0
      let l:cursor_position[2] += l:cursor_x_offset
    else
      let l:cursor_position[2] = 0
    endif
  else
    let l:new_depth = len(repeat('#', l:current_depth + a:depth))
    if l:new_depth > 0
      call MarkDown_Heading_Transform(l:new_depth)
    else
      call MarkDown_Heading_Transform(0)
    endif
    return
  endif

  execute 'normal! 0d$0i' . l:heading_line
  call setpos('.', l:cursor_position)
endfunction
```

> Side note, I'm not sure what's going on with syntax highlighting here, but as of latest revisions these scripts seem to function without error.